# MySQL on custom function with MaxMind GeoLocation

Tags: mysql, sql, function, geolocation

I have followed this tutorial with the latest data from MaxMind:

http://www.atomodo.com/code/how-to-really-import-the-maxmind-geoip-free-country-csv-file-into-mysql

I ran a test:

```
SELECT locid FROM blocks WHERE INET_ATON('174.36.207.186') BETWEEN startIPNum AND endIPNum
```

gave me 12120 in about 5 seconds

```
SELECT city FROM location WHERE locid = 12120;
```

gave me Washington.  Now, I added the custom function (IPTOLOCID) and it is indeed fast when I test like this:

```
SELECT IPTOLOCID("174.36.207.186")
```

it returns 12120 in like .0007 seconds.  But when I try to do this:

```
SELECT city FROM location WHERE locID = IPTOLOCID("174.36.207.186");
```

mysql just hangs... what did I do wrong?

Comment: if i had maxmind DB's installed here I would had tested, but i don't.  Try this : `SELECT city FROM location WHERE locID = (SELECT IPTOLOCID("174.36.207.186"));`

Comment: This also makes mysql hang.  I think it has something to do with the IPTOLOCID function, it's in that tutorial link. SELECT IPTOLOCID("174.36.207.186") by itself returns 12120